# How do you make Mac menu items enable/disable based on the front window in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, menu

I'm writing an app that has 3 different types of windows, plus a settings window. Some of the menu commands affect only one of the window types.

In AppKit, you give your menu items a selector as an action, and a target of nil. The system then walks the responder chain looking for a responder that responds to that selector. If it finds one, it enables the menu item. If not, it disables the menu items. That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI doesn't really support using the responder chain, or sending selectors.

At least not really.

**Problem 1:** You can have a menu command try to send a selector to an object using `tryToPerform(_:with:)`, and you can use the Appkit code `NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder` to send a selector, **but** the SwiftUI way of receiving selectors, using `.onCommand(Selector(("selectorName:")))`, doesn't give you access to the object attached to the send command.

**Minor Problem 1.5:** The compiler doesn't seem able to resolve that adding an `.onCommand` handler to your view means you implement the selector in question, so you can't use the `#selector` construct, and have to use the less safe `Selector(_: String)` way of defining a selector.

**Problem 2:** There's no clean way to see if the responder chain responds to the selector.

What I worked out was to add a global `ObservableObject` state object <**shudder**!> that has `@Published` properties. One of those properties is a bool `keyWindowIs<type>`. Each of my window types implements an `.onChange(of: controlActiveState)` handler. In that handler, if the new state is .key, it sets global properties in my `ObservableObject` that are appropriate for that window. One of those properties is my `keyWindowIs<type>` flag.

I also have to suscribe to window `willCloseNotification`s, by adding an

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWindow.willCloseNotification, object: window))
```

handler to a top level object in my View hierarchy. (I've used the navigation stack.) In that window will close onReceive handler, I set the global state vars to disable menu items that are active for the current window type.

Then, in my menu struct, I apply a   `.disabled(!appSettings.keyWindowIs<type>)` modifier to the objects (Buttons, Pickers, whatever) that need to be enabled/disabled based on the current key window.

So each window maintains the global `appSettings.keyWindowIs<type>` flag as it becomes key, and when a window is closed, it sets that window-type's flag to false.

That is nasty, but it works.

If anybody knows a more elegant (ok, less nasty) way to handle this, I'm all ears.

(I also don't know how to solve the problem with using `#selector` to invoke a selector withtout getting compiler errors.)